# .htaccess not redirecting to ?_escaped_fragment_=

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect the request "`index.php?_escaped_fragment_=about`" to "`snapshots/snap_about.html`"
but I can't get it to work :(

It's an AJAX site; the URL I receive when I try to request `example.com/index.php?_escaped_fragment_=about` is:

```
example.com/index.php?_escaped_fragment_=about#!about
```

This is my htaccess

```
redirect index.php?_escaped_fragment_=about http://www.example.com/snapshots/snap_about.html
redirect  /testx.html http://example.com/dummytest/index.html
```

The redirect /testx.html works.

Maybe I am making a big big mistake, but I am new at this!

Comment: does you index have code which can handle the escaped_fragment request? You can use PHP headers inside the document for a 301 redirect

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do this using a RewriteRule.  Is this a one-off, or is it a general pattern that could be applied to other URLs?  e.g. would you also want
`index.php?_escaped_fragment_=blah` to redirect to `snapshots/snap_blah.html`?

If not, something like this:

```
RewriteRule index\.php\?_escaped_fragment_=about  snapshots/snap_about.html [NC,R=301]
```

If yes, something like:

```
RewriteRule index\.php\?_escaped_fragment_=(.*)  snapshots/snap_$1.html [NC,R=301]
```